# Return data from C# to jQuery UI autocomplete

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I want to populate my `autocomplete` with data from database.
So I wrote a method in c# to read it from db:

```
public string[] GetNames()
{
    var names = unitOfWork.deviceRepository.Get().Select(w=>w.Name);
    return names.ToArray();
}
```

And this works just fine. All needed data is in names.

Now Ajax I'm using to get this data to client side:

```
$(function () {
    var availableTags;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/DeviceUsage/GetNames",
        type: "GET",
        error: function (data) {
            alert("wystąpił nieokreślony błąd " + data);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            availableTags = data;
        }
    })
    $("#deviceName").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

As You can see I'm leaving `dataType` for intelligent guess.
But the console.log in success writes `System.String[]` in console instead of data from `GetNames`. 
Can anyone suggest me how to modify my code to get the autocomplete work?

Comment: Make the return of the GetNames WEB API call a JSONResult and convert your string array to JSon before returning it. Ajax has no idea what to do with a C#/.Net CLR class.

Comment: refer to this tutorial on working sample http://instinctcoder.com/asp-net-mvc-4-jquery-autocomplete-json-2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dataType` is not for C# or MVC or server side, this is to tell jQuery that you are using json response and jQuery should parse it. Since you are not providing it, jQuery will not parse it and thus data is just an string. If you want json, then provide it or use `JSON.parse` to parse your data string.

Either -

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/DeviceUsage/GetNames",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (data) {
            alert("wystąpił nieokreślony błąd " + data);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            availableTags = data;
        }
    })
```

or -

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/DeviceUsage/GetNames",
        type: "GET",
        error: function (data) {
            alert("wystąpił nieokreślony błąd " + data);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(jsonData);
            availableTags = jsonData;
        }
    })
```

And also,  you are not waiting for the ajax to complete before you assign -

```
$("#deviceName").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
```

you should wait for ajax to complete, so take this call inside success like this -

```
success: function (data) {
            //do proper parsing as mentioned earlier
            availableTags = jsonData;
            $("#deviceName").autocomplete({
                 source: availableTags
             }); 
        }
```

because at the moment of call `availableTags` has nothing in it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just expecting a comma-separated string as a return value you could change your `GetNames` function to return a `string` and concat the array using the `String.Join` function.

```
return String.Join(", ", unitOfWork.deviceRepository.Get().Select(w=>w.Name).ToArray());
```

---

But I would personally recommend using some type of `json` value response and return an array of strings as a `json string` (easily parsed by JavaScript).

Something like (using newtonsoft json.net, following sample is not tested):

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(unitOfWork.deviceRepository.Get().Select(w=>w.Name).ToArray());
```

Comment: I tried to get it work but anything I could get is Cannon implicitly convert string to Jsonresult

Comment: Think you could show the function where you call the `GetNames()` function?